# Typescript Interfaces and Promises behaviour

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Could anybody clarify why after Promise, function does not check IUser properly? Is it expected?

```
interface IUser {
  email: string;
  name: string;
}

const testFn = (user: IUser) => { console.log(user); };

testFn({
  email: 'email',
  name: 'name',
  admin: true // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'admin' does not exist in type 'IUser'
});

Promise.resolve({
  email: 'email',
  name: '1',
  admin: true // but this passes
}).then(user => testFn(user));
```

Live example https://codesandbox.io/s/j2ywh?file=/index.ts

Answer (score 0):

No one told `Promise` the type of what it has to resolve, hence it tries to find it by itself by looking at what come next, that is an object with three fields: `email, name and admin`.

You can explicitly force the check with `Promise.resolve<IUser>` and it will throw an error because `admin` shouldn't be there, as expected.

Comment: I had little hope that this could be inferred :)Thanks for your reply!